# Enumerate all the files in directory those may dont have extension

Tags: python

I have to open each file from a directory and parse for string, however some of the file don't have the extension so they are not opening.

#### My code:

```
rootPath = 'G:\\ginipig\\Javascript\\scripts\\script\\SCRIPT\\HTML\\VirTool\\JS\\Obfuscator\\AJ\\193a46bdb29515e3bd08d79593916d9e'
pattern = '*.*'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
    fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
    with open(fullname, 'rb') as infile:
      data = infile.read()
      # my code
```

This code is not parsing files which don't have the extensions. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Rajendra, i don't know how to know if a path is a directory or a file in python, but i think the first step for your issue is your 'pattern' variable: you wrote `*.*`, so you force your script to match only files with extension. 
Perharps you may begin to set this pattern to '*' and then, see if python provides method to identitfy files/directories ?

Comment: Why can you just not do `for f in filenames`, and then just print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your pattern to `pattern = '*'`

This will match all filenames regardless of whether they have a `.` in them or not. Currently you are only matching filenames that contain a `.` which obviously those without extensions do not.

Of course if you want to match every file, there probably isn't any need to use `fnmatch.filter()` at all!

Comment: `'*'` excludes files that start with a dot.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Are you sure? The documentation ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html ) specifically states "Similarly, filenames starting with a period are not special for this module, and are matched by the * and ? patterns."

Comment: you are right. `fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), '*')` behaves differently from `glob.glob('*')` and the shell (to my surprise).

Answer (score 0):

if it is only one dir or folder you might want to try the following:
This does assume no sub dirs exist otherwise you still need the filer

```
import os    

root = 'some/dir/some/where/'

flist = os.listdir(root)
for file in flist:
    fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
    with open(fullname, 'rb') as infile:
       data = infile.read()
       #your code
```